# asp.net mvc - required field from webservice

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, require

I have created a ASP.NET MVC 3 web application. That web application consume a WebServices (asmx) that return a List. I created a View for edit the entity like:

```
@model MvcSWTest.WSRef.entity
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

<h2>Edit</h2>
    @:Title:@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.title)<br />

    @:Date:@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.date)<br /><br />

    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>


}
```

I would like to set the "title" as required field. I cant´t add the [Required] attribute because the "title" is defined on the webservice.

Is there any other way to set a required field in the view or in the controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't adapt you entity class, you should define a custom view model :

```
public class EntityModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public EntityModel(MvcSWTest.WSRef.entity entity)
    {
        this.Title = entity.title;
        this.Date = entity.date;
    }
}
```

You initialize it in your controller, right after getting your data from the web service. You adapt your view to take an `EntityModel` as model, then when you post back to controller, validation will check if `Title` has a valid value, if it's ok you convert your `EntityModel` to `MvcSWTest.WSRef.entity`, before sending back your data.